# check if variable is null - incorrect validation

Tags: php, isnull

This problem is a bit strange. Why is showed "Is not null", if the value sent is null? Any reason for that?

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
lists_owned null
Source
lists_owned=null

<?php
$lists_owned = $_POST['lists_owned'];

var_dump($lists_owned); // string(4) "null"

if(!is_null($_POST['lists_owned'])) {
    echo "Is not null"; I see this echo
}
?>
```

thanks

Comment: Ignacio is right, also, check if `$_POST['lists_owned']` is set before accessing it : `$lists_owned = isset($_POST['lists_owned']) ? $_POST['lists_owned'] : null;` and only use the `$lists_owned` variable after that, it's useless to set $lists_owned and to never use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"null"` is not `null`. If you want to check for `"null"` then you should be using equality.

```
if($_POST['lists_owned'] != 'null') {
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your post value is a string called 'null' and not an actual null value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your value is actually the string "null", not the value null. Ie

```
<?php
$x = "null";
$y = null;
var_dump($x);
var_dump($y);
?>
```

Output

```
string(4) "null"
NULL
```